# Maximal bound running time for an atmega8 cpu progrm

Tags: atmega

Is it correct to say that a program running on an atmega8 CPU (written in embedded C in avr studio) can execute from start to finish in less than one millisecond?

I am referring to the C code in the "forever loop" in the ATMEGA 8. To simplify the analysis for the program,  There is a maximum of 40 variables (integer) in it not floating point. All the instruction in the loop read pins, do some math operations with the input from pins, and then write to pins-there is not another loop in the forever loop. The math operation are +,-, * and / and there are a maximum of 40 variables. All other code can be taken to be the if decision instruction, So its just a sequence of instructions in the forever loop and no jumping back anywhere. So the instructions get processes in sequence and the program does not halt. We also assume such a program fills all the program memory for a C program.

The atmega8 works a 8Mhz (8 million machine cycles per second) with the built in clock, so it seems reasonable to say in 1ms such a C program will run at least a few hundred time-if not massively larger number.

Or do I need to use a crystal to say it will run from start to finish at least once in 1 ms?

The answer is not obvious to me.

If you cant compute the answer what is a good guess?

8mhz means 8000 machine code instructions in 1ms. So the questions is saying if the program (of the form above) runs it slowest, will it take more than 8000 instructions to do the loop once it in 1ms-this seems reasonable to guerss that this is true.

To use an analogy-in some game engines are garunteed to run the  forever loop at 60 times (or frames) per second minimum with whatever code was coded for the game in the loop by the programmer

Comment: 1. We would normally say a `while (1)` loop runs forever, not that it completes once for each pass through the loop.

Comment: 2. As for how long it takes to pass through the loop, how can we know or even guess without knowing the actual code inside the loop?

Comment: @The photon the code wouldnt jump back so it basically would be the time to sequentially go through the most code you could fit into the memory

Comment: and the code is assumed to run from start to finish in the while(1) loop (i.e. the forever loop) in the question

Comment: for example, one of the instructions could be "go to sleep mode".

Comment: @The photon. Iths just the instructions specified in the question so there no sleep function to complicate the analysis

Comment: The question doesn't specify any set of instructions that might be used.

Comment: This is starting to sound similar to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), in the sense that you seem to want to determine the maximum runtime for a program. Usually when I need to determine timing in an embedded system, I either examine the disassembly and count instruction cycles, or I toggle a GPIO pin and *measure* it with an oscilloscope. And even them, I'm more interested in either the duration and stability of a critical section, or I'm interested in the response latency time of the main loop or some other control loop.

Comment: @MarkU I had in mind the program does move through the code sequentially and so it doesnt halt. It goes through all instructions in the forever loop such as like the code given in the answer below. I got a new idea for estimating time . I put it in the comment below. I dont know how you count the cycles with the avr IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The ATMega8 has 8192 Bytes of program ROM. Program memory is 16 bits wide, so it can hold a maximum of 4095 machine code instructions (not counting the reset vector). If a machine code program consisting of nothing but NOPs filled the entire ROM then at 8MHz it would take 4095/8 = ~0.512mS to execute.

But you are considering a C program which includes * and / operators. Multiplying or dividing arbitrary values with straight inline code would consume far too much memory, so the compiler generates code with loops. This takes more cycles to execute than the number of program words used. For example, the code in the `while(1)` loop in this program...

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void){
int i,j;
while (1)
 {
  i=(PINB+37)/11;
  j=(PINC-3)*7;
  PORTD=i+j;  
 }
}
```

... only takes up 64 words of ROM, but takes 248 cycles to execute.

Comment: How did you compute the answer 248?  ~0.512mS seems slow for 4095 instructions. So  your answer is a lower bound.

Comment: As a guess we can take 100 cycles per C instruction that is compiles into machine code (but it probably a lot less than this)  and  4095 for the upper bound for a crude number of C instructions thus if the program memory. Sonce the atmega does 8000000 cycles per second. Thus a crude estimate is then (4095*100)/8000000=0.0511875 seconds or just under 6ms. But it probably 2 cycles for each c instruction. So probably it a lot less than 1 ms.

Comment: The 248 cycles was 'computed' in Atmel Studio's AVR simulator. A C statement could take 1 cycle or 1000 cycles to execute, depending on what machine code the compiler generates to implement it. Some statements may even be optimized out and take no time at all! Any 'crude estimate' based on the source code is just that - and won't give you a reliable upper bound.